# Show All Categories in "Form" Select Option Dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I have about 10 categories and building a search form, But i want to show all categories & even a single category in option. How i can do that? So user can search in all categories with a single phrase.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="searchterm" id="searchterm" placeholder="Start Searching..."  style="width: 60% "/>
<select id="fcat" class="form-control" name="catname" style="width:40%;" required />
<option value="">Select Category</option>
<?php $fetch_category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY categoryname ASC");
   while($throw_category = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_category)) {
 echo '<option value="">All Categories</option> <option value="'.$throw_category['categoryname'].'">'.$throw_category['categoryname'].'</option>'; } ?>
</select>
```

That would be more helpful if you guys could tell me a mysql query to search with a phrase in all categories. I have another table called companies and categories so if someone is search a phrase like "some business name" and select all categories then should show all companies within all categories.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove 'All Categories' option from while loop.
2. Add some value for 'All Categories' option.
3. In the form action page based on the select box option write/generate a query.

Form code

```
 <?php $fetch_category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY categoryname ASC");
   while($throw_category = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_category)) {
     echo ' <option value="'.$throw_category['categoryname'].'">'.$throw_category['categoryname'].'</option>';
   } ?>
     <option value="all">All Categories</option>
</select>
```

Comment: (1 & 2) Ya i understand but i dont know how i can do that. (3) I also dont know know query for the same.